# SharePoint list for inventory database? What would be the best way to do this?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, scheduling, inventory

I need to create a database to maintain a list of about 500 video conferencing rooms, their location, size, capabilities, owners, contacts, equipment (including serial numbers, firmware levels, and service contracts); about 70 fields in all.  The database has to have a customer facing interface (View?) so people can search, filter, and sort rooms to schedule meetings, and a support facing interface that IT Support can use to track licensing, scheduled maintenance, etc...  It would also be great to have a way to kick off a scheduling process (workflow?) after the customer selects a room.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use a SharePoint list & views for this task, or if another product would be better.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, Yes It is possible using SharePoint Lists. I would suggest using Windows SharePoint services (Free version) if you are planing to use SharePoint only for this purpose.

If you have any other specific questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case, excluding S/N's and use a basic sharepoint list. If each video conferencing space has a unique name and/or room #, create a naming convention for sorting. I.E. Polycom Video conferencing room in Los Angeles, building #201 and room #12: VCLA.201.12. Once you can accurately name your spaces, add additional columns for hardware information (Camera, Microphone, Codec, etc.). I've done this for the current company I work for in an effort to establish and operations page on SharePoint. I have in total 170 conference rooms. Use sharepoint designer for ease of use.